# Pass a block variable to a callback function that has already arguments

Tags: node.js, parameters, callback, arguments, scoping

This is my callback:

```
function evaluateServiceResponse(err, response){
  db.answerCollection.insert({id: response["serviceAnswer"]["id"]}); //problem is this line

}
```

This is my callback-user:

```
mysoapclient.invokeServiceMethod(jsonRecords,this.evaluateServiceResponse);
```

Here is the whole code. Inside `process` I create a block reference to my database:

```
process(function(){
  ...
  let db=null;
  db = mongoClient.connect(connectionURL); 
  //Do whatever to create jsonRecords
  mysoapclient.invokeServiceMethod(jsonRecords,this.evaluateServiceResponse);
  ...
});
```

The `invokeServiceMethod` talks to service then calls the callback passing it the service response.

How do I get the db reference into my callback `evaluateServiceResponse`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use closure :

```
function evaluateServiceResponse(db){ 
 return function(err, response){
  db.answerCollection.insert({id: response["serviceAnswer"]["id"]}); //problem is this line
}
}
```

And use like:

```
 mysoapclient.invokeServiceMethod(jsonRecords,this.evaluateServiceResponse(db));
```

Comment: Thanks; that helps:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
function evaluateServiceResponse(err, response, db){
  db.answerCollection.insert({id: response["serviceAnswer"]["id"]}); //problem is this line
}



process(function(){
  let db=null;
  db = mongoClient.connect(connectionURL); 
  //Do whatever to create jsonRecords
  mysoapclient.invokeServiceMethod(jsonRecords, (err, response) => {
    return this.evaluateServiceResponse(err, response, db);
  });
});
```

Comment: This solution is not correct. I think the "this." reference can not be transported into the body of a callback. That is why I got the error at :     TypeError: Cannot read property 'evaluateServiceResponse' of undefined"

Comment: @saab you right. function(err, response) was originally arrow function. Anyway, will fix original code.

Comment: I dont get what you mean. Isn't  this the same code as before, just using a new syntax or am I confusing something? I mean even here the "this" will be undefined.

Comment: @saab nope. Arrow functions are a bit different - they don't have own `this`. Check MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions `An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target).`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I didn't know that about arrow function expression. I think I get this solution, as it is cleaner to read.